Trying to webscrape from the website, but the sale doesn't show up
I tried to web scraping from this website to get the artist song, name, and the sales. But from the codes i wrote below, I do get the artist name and song, but the sales didn't show up in my csv file.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv

url = 'https://circlechart.kr/page_chart/album.circle?nationGbn=T&targetTime=2012&hitYear=2012&termGbn=year&yearTime=3'

# Initialize WebDriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

# Wait until the table is loaded

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ChartTablePC')))

# Locate the table

table = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'ChartTablePC')
rows = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')

# Print structure of each row to verify

for row in rows[:5]:  # Print the first 5 rows for inspection
cells = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
print([cell.text for cell in cells])

# Define headers

HEADERS = ['Rank', 'Album Artist', 'Sales']

# Open CSV file for writing

with open('EXOalbumSales2012.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(HEADERS)

    # Iterate over rows
    for row in rows[1:]:  # Skip the header row
        cells = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
        if len(cells) >= 5:  # Ensure there are enough columns
            rank = cells[0].text.strip()
            album_artist = cells[2].text.strip()
            sales = cells[4].text.strip()
            
            data_out = [rank, album_artist, sales]
            writer.writerow(data_out)
            print(data_out)

# Close the WebDriver

driver.quit()

the expected output should be artist name, song title and album sales inside csv file

Replace
sales = cells[4].text.strip()

With
sales = cells[3].get_attribute("textContent").strip()

The index for sales column should be 3 instead of 4 and you need to fetch the text using get_attribute("textContent")
Full code
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import csv

url = 'https://circlechart.kr/page_chart/album.circle?nationGbn=T&targetTime=2012&hitYear=2012&termGbn=year&yearTime=3'

# Initialize WebDriver
# Initialize Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)

# Wait until the table is loaded

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ChartTablePC')))

# Locate the table

table = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'ChartTablePC')
rows = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')

# Print structure of each row to verify

for row in rows[:5]:  # Print the first 5 rows for inspection
    cells = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
    print([cell.text for cell in cells])

# Define headers

HEADERS = ['Rank', 'Album Artist', 'Sales']

# Open CSV file for writing

with open('EXOalbumSales2012.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(HEADERS)

    # Iterate over rows
    for row in rows[1:]:  # Skip the header row
        cells = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
        if len(cells) >= 5:  # Ensure there are enough columns
            rank = cells[0].text.strip()
            album_artist = cells[2].text.strip()
            sales = cells[3].get_attribute("textContent").strip()
            
            data_out = [rank, album_artist, sales]
            writer.writerow(data_out)
            print(data_out)

# Close the WebDriver

driver.quit()

Output CSV

